# Frame structure is not working

Tags: beamer, listings, block

For my following code, the frame is not working. Latex gives a lot of errors, such as

> Undefined control sequence \end{frame}, 
>   Illegal unit of measure (pt> inserted) \end{frame}

I cannot find any error with my code. Can any one suggest where is the bug?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{listings} %used for source code
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Matlab Generated Plot} 
    \begin{columns}[onlytextwidth]
        \begin{column}{0.45\textwidth}
            \begin{block}{Code}
                \begin{lstlisting}
                    for i:=maxint to 0 do
                    begin
                    { do nothing }
                    end;
                    Write('Case insensitive ');
                    Write('Pascal keywords.');
                \end{lstlisting}
            \end{block}
        \end{column}
        \begin{column}{0.45\textwidth}
        Test
        %\input{fig_x2}
        \end{column}
    \end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your MWE is missing a `\begin{document}`… even adding it doesn't seem to reproduce the error, either. (Adding also `[fragile]` to `\begin{frame}` let's your MWE compile without error…)

Comment: Thanks. the `fragile` was the problem. Adding it fixed it.